# Text Grab from a large content

Tags: php

I need to grab a text that is surrounded within `quotes` assigned to a variable `string`. This is how the content will be

> Inspired and recalling tricks he learned from Doc and his friends,
>   McQueen quickly emerges to lead the race into the final laps. Hicks,
>   refusing to lose, sends Weathers into a dangerous accident. Seeing
>   this and recalling Doc's fate, McQueen stops just short of the finish
>   line, allowing Hicks to win, and drives back to push Weathers over the
>   finish line. The crowd and media condemn Hicks' victory
>   `string="Mickey"` and give praise to McQueen's sportsmanship. Though
>   offered the Dinoco sponsorship deal, McQueen declines, insisting on
>   staying with his current sponsors as an appreciation of their past
>   support.

I need to grab `Mickey` from this whole content.

I tried `substr` on PHP , didn't help though. Any ideas ?

**P.S. The string inside the quotes may vary.**

Comment: Why didn't substr work? Show your code. You should also be able to do it with a regular expression.

Comment: @Barmar, since i don't know the length where to cut off the string.

Comment: Use `strpos()` to find the second doublequote, and cut off there.

Comment: @Barmar, Problem is there can be other quotes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one of these quoted words in the string the easiest thing to do will be:

```
$myArr = explode('"',$string); // break the string to array with " as dilimeter
echo $myArr[1]; // echo the second element.
```

Update: for many quots - pick only the one after `string=`:

```
$myPos = strpos($string,'string="')+8; // get the position of string after 'string="'
$result = substr($string,$myPos,strpos($string,'"',$myPos)-$myPos);

echo $result;
```

**Note: this should be a lot more efficient than using regex - [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1dx-0me)** result:

`Yotam: 0.014078ms, bkilinc: 0.048885ms`

Comment: sorry there can be many quotes too. but i just need to get what is assigned to the variable `string`

Comment: Please upvote my question, so i can vote up your answer as i need 15 rep to upvote.

Comment: just curiosity; why it is a lot more efficient than regex ? the 8 value is hardcoded and may create maintanence problems. overall this is not as concise as regex solution, so where is the efficiency ?

Comment: @bkilinc Simply because 8 is no more hard coded than `"/string\=\"(.*?)\"/"` in the regex. strpos stops looking when it finds a match - preg_match doesn't, consider a case where the `string="something"` is relatively at the start of the string and the rest is very long text (millions of chars), strpos will blast through it while preg_match will keep looking for matches all the way to the end. this kind of tasks is NOT what preg_match was created for..

Comment: preg_match() is created for matching string patterns. It is a C function and pretty fast. And leads to concise and maintainable code.

Comment: @bkilinc you are correct. however if you know in advanced you're going to have only one match you should without a doubt take a different appoarch. What you're doing reminds me of looping through an entire array when looking only for $arr[10]

Comment: will add time results in a sec

Comment: you don't need to add time results. In PHP we are using lots of high level functions.preg_match is good for matching one or more pattern. If you like to extend, you would not think another logic, just change the pattern.

Comment: @bkilinc take a look at this [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1dx-0me) - my code runs more than 3 times faster

Answer (score 3):

I think preg_match should be used like;

```
$matches = Array();
preg_match("/string\=\"(.*?)\"/", $content, $matches);
```

at the end $matches[1] should contain the value.